# Lync 2013 Installation ERROR

Tags: active-directory, server, windows-server-2012, lync-2013

I am trying to install Lync2013 in Windows server2012. I have completed steps like prepare active directory, prepare first STD Edition server, Install Administrative tools and have build Topology. After I complete all these steps when I try to Click on install Lync by going to install or update Lync server system I get an error saying that,

**Error: Prerequisite not satisfied: This product cannot be installed on a domain controller.
? Details
+ Type: BlockingPrereqException
+ ? Stack Trace
    +   at Microsoft.Rtc.Internal.Tools.Bootstrapper.BootstrapperTask.AddMsiPrereq(String prereqName) 
at Microsoft.Rtc.Management.Internal.Utilities.LogWriter.InvokeAndLog[T](Action`1 action, T arg)**

Can some one please tell me where I am doing wrong?? What needs to be done...
My Server (DNS, DHCP, ADDS, ADCS, IIS, RRA, etc..)

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You cannot install Lync 2013 on machine which is responsible for your domain and administrates Active Directory.

In fact, to install Lync 2013 you need to have two machines - first (lets call it M1) acting as Domain Controller, and second (M2) for Lync 2013 installation.

So the solution for your problem is to get the second Win Server machine, then join it to the domain which you've created on M1 and finally install Lync 2013 on M2 - this machine is often called 'Front End' machine in online tutorials.